# Angular ui-select2 "Add" button inside dropdown list

Tags: html, angularjs, ui-select2, angular-ui-select

How can I insert a button inside the dropdown list in ui-select2? Tried to search but can't find any.

---

Sample image.

[image]

See ui-select2 documentation.
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select

Comment: you should keep your new button beside the dropdown instead of inside the dropdown, because dropdown click event won't be considered as button click.

Comment: Have you achieved it?

Comment: I need something like this too...have you solved?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this instead

```
<div class="input-group">
   <--- ui-select here --!>                         
   <span class="input-group-btn">
        <a class="btn btn-default" href="" target="_blank"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a>
   </span>
 </div>
```